# Finding nearest tiepoint in aerial triangulation export from Bentley Context Capture in Cesium

Tags: cesium, bentley

I am trying to solve the problem of clicking a point on a 3D tileset loaded by Cesium, and finding the nearest tiepoint corresponding to the clicked point

Here are the steps that I have taken:

1) Get the Cartesian coordinates:

`cartesian3d = viewer.scene.pickPosition(click.position)`

2) Converting the `Cartesian3` to WGS84 Lat/Long:

`cartographic3d = cartesianToDegrees(viewer.scene.ellipsoid, cartesian3d)`

```
const cartesianToDegrees = (ellipsoid, x) => {
  const carto = ellipsoid.cartesianToCartographic(x);
  const longitude = (carto.longitude * 180) / math.pi;
  const latitude = (carto.latitude * 180) / math.pi;
  return [longitude, latitude, carto.height];
};
```

I have a list of tiepoints from the aerial triangulation step of Bentley Context Capture, this is the reference system that was used: `EPSG:28356`

3) Now to convert the tiepoint:

`tiepoint = (298886.689734013, 6229317.15626832, 26.6625023260713)`

to WGS84 I use `pyproj`:

`in_proj = Proj("EPSG:28356")`

`out_proj = Proj("+init=EPSG:4326")`

`wgs_coords = transform(in_proj, out_proj, x=tiepoint[0], y=tiepoint[1], z=tiepoint[2])`

Which is:
`(150.82094535413248, -34.05758120402254, 26.6625023260713)`

I then do this for all the tiepoints, then I am able to query for the nearest tiepoint using a KD tree.

Now I click on my 3D Cesium tileset to get the cartographic3d coordinate, and try to find the nearest matching tiepoint. The problem is that retrieved doesn't match up to the point that I have clicked on the model, it always seems a few meters off.

I'm thinking that I must have done something wrong with the conversion but I can't seem to find out what it is. If I'm not wrong Cesium uses ECEF for Cartesian3d, and `ellipsoid.cartesianToCartographic` is called I can confirm we are using the `WGS84` ellipsoid.

Am I missing anything?